# Update InboxStyle Notifications with a new line

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I'm trying to implement an InboxStyle notification on my app to make the people see all their last notifications, but i can't find a way to update the last notification, it simply overwrites with the new one even if I use the same NOTIF_ID.

My actual code:

```
private void sendNotification(String notif, String[] args) {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, main_activity.class), 0);


    if (notif.equals("NOTIF_0")){
        notif = String.format(getString(R.string.NOTIF_0), args[0]);
    } else if (notif.equals("NOTIF_1")) {
        notif = String.format(getString(R.string.NOTIF_1), args[0]);
    } else if (notif.equals("NOTIF_2")) {
        notif = String.format(getString(R.string.NOTIF_2), args[0]);
    } else if (notif.equals("NOTIF_2_EX")) {
        notif = String.format(getString(R.string.NOTIF_2_EX), args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    } else if (notif.equals("NOTIF_3")) {
        notif = String.format(getString(R.string.NOTIF_3), args[0]);
    } else if (notif.equals("NOTIF_3_EX")) {
        notif = String.format(getString(R.string.NOTIF_3_EX), args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    } else if (notif.equals("NOTIF_3_EX_DIS")) {
        notif = String.format(getString(R.string.NOTIF_3_EX_DIS), args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    } else if (notif.equals("NOTIF_4")) {
        notif = String.format(getString(R.string.NOTIF_4), args[0]);
    } else if (notif.equals("NOTIF_5")) {
        notif = String.format(getString(R.string.NOTIF_5), args[0]);
    } else if (notif.equals("NOTIF_5_EX")) {
        notif = String.format(getString(R.string.NOTIF_5_EX), args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    } else if (notif.equals("NOTIF_6_EX")) {
        notif = String.format(getString(R.string.NOTIF_6_EX), args[0], args[1]);
    } else if (notif.equals("NOTIF_31")) {
        notif = String.format(getString(R.string.NOTIF_31), args[0]);
    }

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    inboxStyle.addLine(notif);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(notif);

    mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

    notification.flags    |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.flags    |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
    notification.ledOnMS = 300;
    notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
    notification.flags    |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

Extra questions: Is there a way to display only the last 5 notifications (the new one and the 4 newer from the last notification)?
I'm also searching a way to display a BigView instead of an InboxStyle, but only when there's only one notification active, otherwise the notification should be displayed as a list, is it possible to see if a notification with the same ID is present and load one or another style based on that check? Can't find any info about it on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to do in an ugly way for now. I save my last notifications in a SQLite DB, retrieve them any time and build the updated notification.
I clean the DB when I launch the app so next time the user will have only new notification.

I don't know if this is the best solution, but I can't find any API to access the old notification to retrieve info from it so I implemented this solution.